# How to get all descendant text content in XML using XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

**XML file**

```
<TEXT>
    <DESCR>
         Here is the first part...
         <PLUS>The second</PLUS>
         And the third
    </DESCR>
</TEXT>
```

**What I expect to get:**

```
Here is the first part...The secondAnd the third
```

**What I actually get:**

```
Here is the first part...And the third.
```

I tried `descendant-or-self::*` xPath function, child, and descendant, no result.

If someone can tell me how to get the text in the child nodes too.

Comment: I would advice to change the content of your XML. A node that has text content and child nodes is never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but if I could do it, I would ! Unfortunatelly, we use a software which generate this XML file.. I can't change it !

Comment: ah, I see, maybe one of the solutions below will work for you.

Comment: Could you post the specific *PHP* code you ran that got the wrong output? It's a little unclear at the moment exactly what you've tried.

Comment: @ErikL It's not that uncommon to use XML as a format for inline markup of text - see XHTML, DocBook, etc. It does require a slightly different way of working, though, because you can't think of a single text node as the "value" of an element.

Comment: @ErikL:  ***Your request for OP to change the XML not to use mixed content is entirely misguided.***  Although yours might be a data-centric view, there's an entire document-centric perspective that you're missing.

Comment: I guess I'm encountering XML only in a data-centric view in my day to day business. my bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

You ***cannot*** perform the concatenation of all text descendents of a given node within XPath 1.0.  You can select the nodes in XPath,

```
/TEXT/DESCR//text()
```

but then you'll have to perform the concatenation in the hosting language.

**In PHP:**

```
$xml = '<TEXT>
    <DESCR>
         Here is the first part...
         <PLUS>The second</PLUS>
         And the third
    </DESCR>
</TEXT>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$x= new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($x->query("/TEXT/DESCR//text()") as $node) echo trim($node->textContent);
```

Will output the result you requested:

```
Here is the first part...The secondAnd the third
```

[Alternatively if you've no other reason to iterate over the text nodes, replace the `foreach` loop above with:]

```
$xml = '<TEXT>
    <DESCR>
         Here is the first part...
         <PLUS>The second</PLUS>
         And the third
    </DESCR>
</TEXT>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$x= new DOMXpath($dom);
echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $x->evaluate('normalize-space(/TEXT/DESCR)'));
```

Which yields:

```
Here is the first part... The second And the third
```

### XPath 2.0

You ***can*** perform the concatenation of all text descendents of a given node within XPath 2.0:

```
string-join(/TEXT/DESCR//text(), '')
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the XML processor used by all PHP extensions is [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/html/index.html), which only supports XPath 1.0.

Comment: @IMSoP: Absolutely correct.  XPath 2.0 solution is for the benefit of those whose hosting language/library supports XPath 2.0, which libxml2 does not.

Comment: I would like to try this, but I don't know how to call string-join function..
    echo string-join(('Test','Test','Test'),'/'); But it doesn't work ('unexpected ',')

Comment: You're welcome.  As @IMSoP mentioned, only XPath 1.0 is available in PHP.  Besides, you'd have to position the `string-join` as an XPath, not a PHP call as you have it in your comment.

Comment: @kjhughes could you explain me how to call it then ?

Comment: As part of the XPath, `string-join()` would be in the XPath argument to `evaluate()` or `query()`, but you cannot use `string-join()` because it requires XPath 2.0 and PHP only has XPath 1.0.  Go with one of the XPath 1.0 solutions I've shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your input XML, this might work:

```
concat(/TEXT/DESCR,/TEXT/DESCR/PLUS)
```

or

```
string-join(/TEXT/DESCR/descendant-or-self::text())
```